# Convex segmentation in 3D from just points?

Tags: algorithm

I have a set of 3D points. The coordinates are all integers with no decimals to worry about.

I have to convert these points to a collection of convex hulls (point collections only - the triangulation code is already done and working).

The goal is to create pseudo-concave meshes from points via convex segmentation. Overlapping meshes as well as incorrect normals are not concerns in this case.

The points have no index nor connectivity structure amongst themselves. Rather, connectivity in my program is assumed by:

-All neighbors are considered. (Like 8-way searching in 2D).

-A neighbor in my program is exactly the same as in image processing - distances greater than 1 unit assume the points are not neighbors.

The question is, does an algorithm exist for this?

Here's an image to help describe the desired effect:
(Note that I don't have the 10 reputation points to post it directly. It's just a link.)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvNmM.jpg